# Can't seem to get Col-4 Working on Laravel

Tags: laravel, multiple-columns

So I am trying to create a car sales website using Laravel. The code presented shows 20 Cars from the database being shown but all one after the other. I want it to appear in columns of 3 or 4 if possible. I've been trying to use col-4 but it doesn't make any difference. Any help appreciated. The only answer I could find online was that the container was within the row but I don't have this issue so unsure.

```
<div class="container text-center">
  <h2>Cars</h2>

  <div class="row">

    @foreach ($allcars as $car)

    <div class="col-4">
      <div class="card">
          <img class="card-img-top" src="{{asset('qashqai.jpg')}}" alt="Card 
          image cap">
          <div class="card-body">
              <h4 class="card-title">{{$car->name}}</h4>
              <p class="card-text">{{$car->description}}</p>
          </div>
          <div class="card-body">
              <a href="#" class="card-link">Card link</a>
              <a href="#" class="card-link">Another link</a>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    @endforeach
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, could you please show us the html code you are working on? We cannot state whats wrong just by your story. Please make sure the example includes your links to bootstrap css.

Comment: Sorry I know I'm trying to add it bare with me not used to stackoverflow sorry

Comment: Not a problem, just making sure the issue contains enough info, so you can get the help you need ;)

Comment: Thanks, think I have the appropriate code up now

Comment: Are you using bootstrap? If yes please refer [this](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/)

Comment: Should col-3 not work? I've seen a few people use this on youtube just unsure why its not working for me